# MySql auto-increment not working while inserting multiple rows

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I am inserting multiple rows in the MySql database table the first row is getting inserted but for remaining it is showing the error:

```
[Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY']
  code: 'ER_DUP_ENTRY',
  errno: 1062,
  sqlState: '23000',
  index: 1,
```

This is the structure of `id` field:

[image]

**If I insert a single row the auto-increment works file.**

I am not able to rectify the problem. Please help. Thanks.

**EDIT**

I am using [node-rom2](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2) and the code is

```
modelObj.create(arrayOfObjects, function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
         console.log("The error is :", err);
      }
      else {
         response.status = 'success';
         response.data = result;
      }
    next(response);
});
```

**The SQL query is generated dynamically.**

Comment: If insering multiple row then don't insert column id in mysql query. it will be inserted automatically.

Comment: Also please send your mysql query your are trying to insert.

Comment: Are you inserting the ID column value also?

Comment: your insert query should not contain id column

Comment: @Jyoti_Mishra, I am not inserting `id`, I am just sending other values.

Comment: Please mention your query.

Comment: @* What is wrong with my question? (Why marked as -ve)

Comment: I think your arrayOfObjects make Query like 

**insert into tableName (id,....) values(2,.....)** make sure in your insert query there is no ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I got the solution, the mistake I was doing is I was generating the data using a `for loop` like this:

```
var data = { name:'john', age:24, email:'abc@abcd.com'};

var arrayOfObjects= [];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   arrayOfObjects.push(data);
}

modelObj.create(arrayOfObjects, function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
         console.log("The error is :", err);
      }
      else {
         response.status = 'success';
         response.data = result;
      }
    next(response);
});
```

So **each and every record is same in this condition**. However other than `id` none column having the property `primary-key`. *I think it can be the behavior of the database or the node-orm2 can also be the reason*, so it is not accepting the exact same values.

In actual, all the record won't be same. If you have some other point please let me know your thoughts. Thanks.